# Vim: substitute once, starting from CURSOR position (not line)

Tags: vim

Is there a simple way (without too many keystrokes), to substitute the next occurrence of a pattern (in the line or in the whole document, both would be interesting), starting from the cursor position?

So far, I've only come up with selecting onwards, going to normal mode, and doing `:s/\%Vpattern/rep`. It's too cumbersome. Perhaps there's a nice way to select the next occurrance of a pattern, and then one can "change" the selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

Just search for the pattern, using <kbd>/</kbd>

Select using <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>

Once selected, you can perform any action on it. Like `y` to copy, `c` to change etc

```
:h gn
```

Comment: I had no clue of `gn`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the confirm option with your substitution. Use the command

```
:%s/pattern/replacement/gc
```

It will take you through each occurrence of the pattern. Type <kbd>y</kbd> to replace, <kbd>n</kbd> to move on without replacing, and <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the search.

Comment: It's very usable (though not ideal if there are other instances in the line). Thanks!

Comment: If you only want to see the first instance on each line you can just leave of the `g` flag at the end.